# How to make a "business card" from a string ObjectListView C#

Tags: c#, objectlistview

please tell me how to present each row(consisting of several columns) in this form.
(You need to have only one such card on one line, not 2 or more, as in the example)
Moved from DataGridView and I'm still having a hard time with ObjectListView
Thank you in advance
[FirstImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjvsr.png)
[SecondImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVkD1.png)

The image with these people was obtained from this site **objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/cookbook-ownerdraw.htm**. I only have code that performs line-by-line filling(as in the table), but I need it as in the pictures

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ObjectListViewList.Count; i++)
{
    AddObjectListView newObject = new AddObjectListView(ObjectListViewList[i][0],
    ObjectListViewList[i][1], ObjectListViewList[i][2], ObjectListViewList[i][3],
    ObjectListViewList[i][4], ObjectListViewList[i][5], ObjectListViewList[i][6], ObjectListViewList[i][7], ObjectListViewList[i][8]);
    objectListView1.AddObject(newObject);
}
```

This is how my [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2tsq.jpg) is filled in.

The data is not exactly the same as in the "business card" example, but this is not critical. I want to understand the principle of creating such a "business card". If someone found ready-made examples, I would be happy if you shared them

Comment: Question: are these real people? if so, please render the images inrecognizable

Comment: Oh, and please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is follow the instructions, download the demo, and then you can see for yourself how this is actually done.

The Cookbook documentation (for which you provided the link) says:

> **Owner drawing in non-Details view**
>
> If you are keen, you can also owner draw the other views too, the non-Details views.
>
> To do this, you install a renderer on your primary column (column 0),
> and do your rendering like normal. The only slight difference is that
> your renderer will have to check which view the ObjectListView is
> currently using before doing your rendering Suppose you only want to
> inflict your gradients on your users when the ObjectListView was in
> Tile view.

So this explains the basic, in that you need to be in a "non-detail" view, and use your own renderer.

If you then download the demo:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/

You can find the file "BusinessCardRenderer.cs", which shows the code which you need to create your own renderer.

I suggest you download and compile the demo and debug it and use it as a reference to your own code.

You can then come back and ask questions about any specific problem you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help) I want to output line-by-line data and just draw a line after the last data, so it looks like a tile)
I couldn't thoroughly understand the examples, so I came up with such a solution.
It remains only to understand how to draw a line under each fourth line